# Calling one function from another in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first time making a project of this size (this is a small section) and this is  also the first time that I have tried using Tkinter so I have very little knowledge of it. When I try to use the first function  `game()` it doesn't wait for the user input. As well as this I cant get it go to the next function `takeitem()` if the user wants to (they should be able to choose to quit rather then it just quitting straight away or going into an infinite loop) 
I have tried to use a return function but that would just crash Tkinter. I tried  `Command_Line.bind("<Return>", takeitem)` with the if statments after this for example

```
Command_Line.bind("<Return>", takeitem)
    if lowerResponse == "yes"
```

If I didn't  use `break` after `if lowerResponse == "yes"` the code would go into an infinite loop so nothing would be displayed.

Below is part of my code which will show what my input functions are called as well as the other the project should run in.

I have been looking at this same error now for 2 days and still don't understand how to fix it after doing some research on youtube. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you would like to know anything else or anything more specific just let me know and I will add it

```
from chancecheck import *#this imports anothe file i created called chance 
check
from fightchance import *
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

root = tk.Tk()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 0)

Main_Textbox = tk.Text(root, width = 83, height = 20)
Main_Textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

Command_Line = tk.Entry(root)
Command_Line.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
Command_Line.config(background = "black", foreground = "white")

def start_text(): #used to start the program
start_command = " do you wish to start the game and begin your journey  \n"
Main_Textbox.delete(1.0, "end")
Main_Textbox.insert("end", start_command)

def update_textbox(x): # this is used to update the text box by clearing what is in the command line and adding new text to the output textbox
Main_Textbox.insert("end", x)
Main_Textbox.see("end")
Command_Line.delete(0, "end")

def process_commands(Event=None):
game()

def lowerStringVar(var):
var=var.lower()
return var

def game():   
weapons=[]#list that i will assign weapons to
inv = []#player inventory for minor lowerResponses
loopa = False
loop = 0
dead = False
begin = True
takeitem = False
gold=0#sets the gold of the player to 0
low = 100
   # while dead == False:

    if begin == True:#just a simple starting sequence to introduce the player to the game
        response = Command_Line.get()
        commands()     
        lowerResponse = lowerStringVar(response)
        if lowerResponse == "yes" or  lowerResponse =="yeah" or lowerResponse == "ye" or lowerResponse== "y":
            update_textbox (" a wise choice \n")
            begin = False
        elif lowerResponse == "commands":
            update_textbox (" take that as a yes then \n")
            commands()
            begin = False
        else:
            update_textbox ("cant say im not disapointed \n")
            update_textbox ("ah well you will be back with time\n")
           # quit(1)
            break

#user is asked if they would like to start with an item()
def takeitem ():
   # while takeitem == False:
    displayintro()
    update_textbox(" would you like to start with an item  ")
    response = Command_Line.get()
    lowerResponse = lowerStringVar(response)
    if lowerResponse == "yes"  or lowerResponse == "yeah"  or lowerResponse == "ye" or lowerResponse =="y":
        takeitem = True
        update_textbox(" well then what would you like")
        update_textbox(" the pendant,the dagger,the gold or the key  ")
        response = Command_Line.get()
        lowerResponse = lowerStringVar(response)
        if lowerResponse == "gold" or lowerResponse == "the gold":
            gold = gold + 200
            update_textbox (" gold it is then")
            loop = False
        elif lowerResponse == "dagger" or lowerResponse == "rusted dagger" or lowerResponse == "small rusted dagger":
            update_textbox ("you take the dagger")
            weapons.append("dagger")
            loop = False
        elif lowerResponse =="key" or lowerResponse == "thief" or lowerResponse == "key of theif" or lowerResponse == "the key":
            update_textbox (" you take the key")
            inv.append("key")
        elif lowerResponse =="pendant" or lowerResponse == "pendant of old gods " or lowerResponse == "old gods" or lowerResponse == "gods":
            update_textbox (" you take the pendant")
            inv.append("pendant")
            loop = False
    elif lowerResponse == "no" or lowerResponse == "nope" or lowerResponse == "n":
        takeitem = True
        update_textbox("well on your way then")
        loop = False
    elif lowerResponse =="commands":
         update_textbox (" no you're not getting them")
         update_textbox ("i have told you what to do and you shouldnt need help with this")
         takeitem = False


    else:
        takeitem == False
        update_textbox("sigh looks like we are going to go through this again then")


Command_Line.bind("<Return>", process_commands)
start_text()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creating a GUI requires a different approach to programming compared to a simple command line program. Everything is based on events. If you put large while loops inside GUI code, the GUI will become unresponsive.

Comment: I have removed both while loops and still have the same problem. It seems that i  need to tell the code to wait for an input after each output but I don't know how to do this